# stange -I effect with make and bad -L

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build an automated build system. It took me a little while to change a working wii generic makefile to a working win32 (using mingw32) makefile.

my make is here http://pastie.org/319482

The weird effect is, if i remove the a preceding the paths in ABS_INCL (line 31) the build doesnt work and complains about missing a header which is specified by the first path. Why is it doing this? i cant track the problem down.

The next issue is when i dropped in code that requires libcurl, i can still compile but no longer link as expected. I added curl to my libs (line 47) and the path (line 53) and it looks like i am including it right and the lib is in the right order (i tried to touch as little as possible while converting wii to win32) and i cant see the problem. Does anyone know why this is happening?

here is simple source to test with

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main2();
int main( int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int a=0;
    printf("hey");
    main2();
    return 0;
}
#include <curl/curl.h>
void main2()
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting a lot of answers here - I'm going to go out on a limb and tell you it's because of your really badly written title. I've read it maybe 20 times as it scrolled down the home page and I still don't really get it. There is the obvious spelling mistake, and I want to go in and fix that but then there is the whole weirdness with the "-l" and "-L" and I can't tell where you are going with that.

So, most people will look at that and just blank out and move on. Assuming they get past that, you failed to add the useful information contained within your makefile to the question and so you've gotta go off and read it on the other site.

Finally, as one more hurdle, your makefile is too long to easily read and absorb. So assuming someone like me who is really kind of determined goes and reads it, it's too difficult to tell where the problem could lie within that. You need to edit it down to probably ten lines or less, and then assuming you haven't been able to figure out the problem, you could then post just those few lines that showed the problem in your question and then with a decent title and some good descriptive text, you'll probably get your answer.

I'm guessing the answer to your question isn't even that hard, you've successfully managed to obfuscate it to the point that most people wont even bother.